# Setting up Bluetooth is always a pain

Tags: bluetooth, rhythmbox, headphones

I have a Jabra Solemate that I had working in the past.  I don't use it often.  I periodically reinstall Ubuntu.

The Solemate registers successfully under the Bluetooth manager and I hear the device itself announce "Solemate is connected."  All of this seems simple enough.  However, once I attempt to play any music on Rhythmbox or youtube, the laptop speakers play instead.  All of this despite having an apparently good Bluetooth connection.  This preempts the act of listening to music with an agitation.

Is there something obvious I need to be doing to get audio to redirect?

The Bluetooth device is set to connect as a headphones device.  When I plug headphones into my computer I never experience an issue.  It always redirects the audio to the headphones.  Bluetooth should be this easy.  That it's not makes me not want to bother using it.  It regularly starts with a bad experience of trying to redirect audio.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried selecting output device after connecting, as you can see in this picture?

[image: Selecting the correct output should solve your issue]

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  My ubuntu kept on giving me issues (14.04 LTS) so I reverted to OSX.  It's not an issue now.  I may give 16.04 LTS a try after a while.